# loading waiting animation on just a specific div(freez just specific part)

Tags: javascript, jquery

lets say I have a page with 3 div and each of them are loaded with differen ajax call.

so for example div1 may take 30 sec to be loaded and div2, 4 sec so I need different waiting animation for them to show they are loading.

I found these links helpful: [link1](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/ajax_ajaxcomplete.asp)

[link2](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/tryit.asp?filename=tryjquery_ajax_ajaxcomplete)

but the prblem is that on any click on button the whole page freezes

I want for example on any click on button special section for example a div freezes and shows the animation

Is that possible? can anyone help?

Update:

Here is jfiddle link:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $(document).ajaxStart(function(){
$("#wait").css("display","block");
});
 $(document).ajaxComplete(function(){
$("#wait").css("display","none");
});
$("button").click(function(){
$("#txt").load("demo_ajax_load.asp");
 });
 });
```

[jfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hminaee/b2HB6/)

Comment: I think a jsfiddle would be in place here.

Comment: Please see the update for jfiddle link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to target your elements relatively, using classes rather than IDs (which must be unique). Here's a simplified demo:

http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/N5V4q/

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("button").click(function () {
        $(this).next(".wait").show();
    });
});
```

If I knew a little more about your ajax calls I might help further.

Comment: Thanks a million, what you created in fiddle was what I wanted